# Best way to create a custom View class from an xml layout file?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-view

I have a RelativeLayout defined in an xml layout file named 'myview.xml' which contains a number of sub-Views (TextViews, ImageViews etc).

I want to create a View object/class named 'MyView' that represents this RelativeLayout, which allows me to change the properties of the sub-Views using methods I will define and such that I can add (and retrieve) instances of MyView programmatically to (from) other Views.

What is the best way to do this? At the moment I am creating a class named 'MyView' which extends FrameLayout and in overriding FrameLayout's three constructors I call the following methods...

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myview, null);
addView(view);
```

... This works but it means all my RelativeLayouts are contained within FrameLayouts and thus I have an extra (unnecessary) layer in my view hierarchy...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do pretty much the same thing. But I send in 'this' rather than null and don't add that view to the parent view.

```
LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
inflater.inflate(R.layout.myview, this);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Mad Mik. If I understand the `inflate` method correctly, it still means I have an extra layer in my view hierarchy but glad to know I'm not alone doing it as I'm doing it, and your way has one less method call so gonna go with that! :)